# Getting row count of foreign key table's rows on the basis of Primary key table's Primary key

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, sql

As usual in PK and Fk relationship.

I am having two tables one is lets say `items_info` and second is `poll_report`

**items_info** structure is as follows

```
 _id       Autogenerated integer based PK

Question   varchar(255)
```

**poll_report**

```
_id       Autogenerated integer based PK

questionId FK to prev table's _id

answerId  integer

deviceId  UNIQUE
```

I want to fetch following type of data using single query.

```
items_info._id   |  items_info.Question  |  count(poll_report.answerId) where poll_report.answerId  == 1 |  count(poll_report.answerId) where poll_report.answerId == 2
```

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like like this:

```
select items_info._id , items_info.Question , sum(poll_report.answerId =1) , sum(poll_report.answerId =2) from items_info,poll_report where items_info._id=poll_report.questionId group by items_info._id;
```

Anyway, the key thing is that you can do this:

```
sum(poll_report.answerId = 1)
```

Comment: Good , you r genius , is this query performance wise good? I dont know about that.